# What is the distribution of $|X-Y|$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are $U(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to find the distribution of $Z = |X-Y|$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform over $(0, 1)$ and independent. The answer I am getting is very close to the one given but I can't figure out why they're different at all.

My method is as follows:

$$
Z = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&X-Y &&\text{if }  X \ge Y \\
&Y-X &&\text{if }  X \lt Y \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

If $Z = X - Y$ then $Y = X-Z$ and so

$$f_z = \int_a^bf_x(x)f_y(x-z)dx $$

To determine $a$ and $b$:
$$0 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } z \le x \le 1+z$$

Since $Z$ is always bigger  than 0, the bounds for the integral are $z$ and $1$.

$$f_z = \int_z^1dx = 1-z$$

Repeating the same process for $Z = Y-X$,

$$f_z = \int_a^bf_x(x)f_y(x+z)dx$$
$$0\le x \le 1 \text{ and }-z \le x \le 1-z $$

Again since $Z$ is always positive, the integral becomes

$$f_z = \int_0^{1-z}dx = 1-z$$

Putting everything together,

$$
f_z = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1-z &&\text{if }  X \ge Y \\
&1-z &&\text{if }  X \lt Y \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

...or just $1-z$.

However the answer provided states that $f_z = -2(z-1)$, which is just $2$ times what I have. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure where you went wrong but the problem is easily solved by finding $P(Z<z)$ and then differentiating.  Also, you can tell that your answer is wrong because the possible values of $z$ are from $0$ to $1$ and if you integrate $1-z$ over this interval you don't get $1$.

Comment: I think it is because you do a distinction of cases, but should actually sum both: since $\mathbb{P}\{Z\in dz\} = \mathbb{P}\{X-Y\in dz\}\cup\{Y-X\in dz\} = \mathbb{P}\{X-Y\in dz\} + \mathbb{P}\{Y-X\in dz\}$ (the two events are disjoint, except on the event of measure $0$ where $X=Y$)

Comment: Your answer is not a possible answer. The probability that $Z\le z$ (and the density) are functions of $z$, $X$ and $Y$ have disappeared, there can be no reference to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of answering the question would be to find the probability that $Z\le z$. For $z$ between $0$ and $1$, this is the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of the unit square that is between the lines $y=x+z$ and $y=x-z$.

Draw a picture. The region consists of the whole square apart from $2$ isosceles right triangles with legs $1-z$. These two triangles have combined area $(1-z)^2$, so the required probability is $1-(1-z)^2$. This is $2z-z^2$. For the density function between $0$ and $1$, differentiate.